# Why does Alt Gr have the same keyCode as Ctrl?

Tags: javascript, keycode

I was having a play with this [script](http://jsfiddle.net/Rw4km/).

And I noticed that <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>'s KeyCode is **17** in IE10 and **17 AND 18** in Chrome?

Can someone explain why its not **18** (or a completely new number) and why I get two popups in Chrome?

Heres the code:

```
document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;
function KeyCheck(e) {
    var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
    alert(KeyID);
    switch (KeyID)
    {
        case 18:
            document.Form1.KeyName.value = "Alt";
            break;
        case 17:
            document.Form1.KeyName.value = "Ctrl";
            break;
    }
}
```

This is not my code, I just stumbled upon it.

**EDIT**: Having more of a play around I believe <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> means <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> at the same time, as some things that require <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> like *é* also work with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Comment: `AltGr` ===  `CTRL` + `ALT`, though after your edit looks like you know that already. Looks like Chrome triggers both pressed, when pressing `AltGr`.

Comment: It's interesting how chrome doesnt say "check this box to prevent the page from creating multiple dialogs"

Comment: It's a different source creating the alert. If you hit the same key twice, you'll get the the check box.

Comment: Are you sure about IE? I just checked it with both IE and Firefox, and I get both Alt and Ctrl(remove the `alert`, and change it to _append_ to the form, the first `alert` seems to stop the second `onkeyup` from firing).

Comment: By the way, you may not rely on this. On my Linux machine with German keyboard layout, `AltGr` is a different keycode, namely 225 (`Ctrl`: 17, `Alt`: 18).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Problem is that the `alert` halts execution of the code, so the second `onkeyup` is not called. By changing the function to

```
function KeyCheck(e)
{
    var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
    switch(KeyID)
    {
    case 18:
        document.Form1.KeyName.value = document.Form1.KeyName.value+"Alt";
        break; 
    case 17:
        document.Form1.KeyName.value = document.Form1.KeyName.value+"Ctrl";
        break;
    }
}
```

we can see that both `Alt` and `Ctrl` get called.

Tested with Firefox 22 and IE 9.